# VHDL State machine stucks in an impossible state

Tags: vhdl, state-machine

I wrote a VHDL State Machine. It works some time until it gets stuck on an impossible state.

There are 7 states in total, but only two of them interesting for us. The state graph is simple:

`IDLE2` <=> `IDLE` <=> Other states

In words, it means that initial state is `IDLE`. All other states can be reached through `IDLE` state. State `IDLE2` can only jump to the `IDLE` state.

Fragment of the code:

```
ENTITY MC_PLD_vhd IS
    PORT
    (
        --INPUTS
        MC_WR: IN STD_LOGIC;
        MC_RD: IN STD_LOGIC;
        Tstart: IN STD_LOGIC;
        CLK: IN STD_LOGIC;
        --OUTPUTS
        PLD_WR: OUT STD_LOGIC;
        PLD_RD: OUT STD_LOGIC;
        STS: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0)
    );
END MC_PLD_vhd;

ARCHITECTURE MC_PLD_vhd_dff OF MC_PLD_vhd IS
    TYPE tSTATE is 
    (
        IDLE   --0
        ,REC1  --1
        ,SEND1 --2
        --I omit some not significant states
        ,IDLE2 --6
         
    );
    SIGNAL STATE :tSTATE := IDLE;
BEGIN
    PROCESS(CLK) IS
    BEGIN
        IF RISING_EDGE(CLK) THEN
            STS <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(tSTATE'pos(STATE), 8));
            CASE STATE IS
                WHEN IDLE =>
                    IF Tstart = '1' THEN
                        PLD_WR <= '1';
                        PLD_RD <= '0';
                        STATE <= SEND1; -- <!> stuck
                    ELSE
                        IF MC_WR = '1' THEN 
                            PLD_RD <= '1';
                            PLD_WR <= '0';
                            STATE <= REC1;
                        ELSE
                            PLD_WR <= '0';
                            PLD_RD <= '0';
                            STATE <= IDLE2;
                        END IF;
                    END IF;
                WHEN IDLE2 =>
                        PLD_WR <= '0';
                        PLD_RD <= '0';
                        STATE <= IDLE;
                WHEN IsReceiving_wait_RD_rise_1 => <...>
-- Other left away, as they don't add any information to my question.
```

As you may notice, the `IDLE` state is not 'stable'. Every cycle the machine must leave the `IDLE` state, even if nothing is happening: `IDLE` jumps to `IDLE2`, and from `IDLE2` it returns to `IDLE` the next clock cycle. And it works pretty well!

Also you may notice that I output `STATE` through `STS` independently from state. In Altera SignalTap I see normal operation: states jumps back and forth, and enters to other states at appropriate input events.

## PROBLEM

Suddenly after many cycles of normal operation I see (in SignalTap) that `STS = 0` and doesn't change in time. This means that `STATE = IDLE`, and the machine does NOT jump to `IDLE2` (`STS = 6`). And it does NOT jump to any state by any input event, it's just stuck in state `IDLE`. Judging by outputs (`PLD_WR = 1` and `PLD_RD = 0`) the code is stuck near the comment `<!> stuck` in the code above, but `STATE <= SEND1` doesn't occur.

## How can this be possible??

Disclaimer: The state `IDLE2` and the output `STS` were implemented for debugging this particular problem.

Comment: Did your clock stop? Otherwise, your code looks reasonable. For more debugging, add a new signal right after `STS <= ...;` that is `STS_d1 <= STS; STS_d2 <= STS_d1`, and then set a trigger in signal tap when `STS = STS_d1 = STS_d2 = 0x0`

Comment: @Bill, Clock works fine, because of an other unrelated logic works. Surprisingly, I managed to solve the problem change switch-enum block to if-integer.

Comment: see matthew's comment below, with your answer.

Comment: and you an use `if`->`elsif`->`else`->`end if`, instead of `if`->`else if`->`else`->`end if`->`end if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, I managed to solve my own problem just after I posted this question, despite the fact that I struggled with it a several days!

**ANSWER**:  I change **switch-enum** block to **if-integer**.

```
    PROCESS(CLK) IS
        CONSTANT STATE_IDLE :INTEGER := 0;
        CONSTANT STATE_RECEIVE :INTEGER := 1;
        --I omit other states
        CONSTANT STATE_IDLE2 :INTEGER := 6;
        VARIABLE STATE :INTEGER := 0;
    BEGIN
        IF RISING_EDGE(CLK) THEN
            STS <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(STATE, 8));
            IF STATE = STATE_IDLE THEN
                IF Tstart = '1' THEN
                    PLD_WR <= '1';
                    PLD_RD <= '0';
                    STATE := STATE_SEND_wait_RD;
                ELSE
                    IF MC_WR = '1' THEN 
                        PLD_RD <= '1';
                        PLD_WR <= '0';
                        STATE := STATE_RECEIVE;
                    ELSE
                        PLD_WR <= '0';
                        PLD_RD <= '0';
                        STATE := STATE_IDLE2;
                    END IF;
                END IF;
        ELSIF STATE = STATE_IDLE2 THEN
            PLD_WR <= '0';
            PLD_RD <= '0';
            STATE := STATE_IDLE;
        ELSIF STATE = STATE_RECEIVE THEN 
--Unsignificant states omitted
```

Further, I cut out debugging **STS** output and **IDLE2** state because they are no longer needed. And it still works, fortunately!

But I'm still wondering why **switch-enum** does not properly work.
May be it's compiler fault, I use "good old" Quartus II 8.1 Web

Comment: Are the inputs from an asynchronous domain? (a sensor, a switch, another clock?) If so, are they synchronised properly?

Comment: What matthew is saying here is the most common reason for state machines to be stuck in undefined states. All inputs to a state machine need to be fully clock synchronous, or your fsm state will be corrupted.

Comment: You never showed us the `when Others` clause in your Case statement, for a start. Also, Matthew is spot on that asynch inputs MUST be resynchronised to Clock. This plagues `IF` statements too, though the consequences may be different.. (And there's nothing wrong with testing enums in an IF statement, reverting to numbers is quite unnecessary)